# prevent property undefined error in using desturcturing

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is my original code

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'
const getUser = () => {
  const {user} = Cookies.getJSON('user')
  if (user) return user
}
```

I got user is undefined error because user cookie doesn't exist.

I have to change it to

```
const getUser = () => {
  const cookie = Cookies.getJSON('user')
  if (!cookie) return false

  if (cookie.user) return cookie.user
}
```

Is there any more elegant way to prevent undefined error when doing desturcturing?

Comment: Or, `const {user} = Cookies.getJSON('user') || {}`

Comment: `return Cookies.getJSON('user')?.user ?? false;`

Answer (score 0):

One way to prevent it  is to use `||` :

```
const {user} = Cookies.getJSON('user') || {};
```

Comment: but it's still subtle, should I do this every time I do desturcturing?

Answer (score 0):

In case you like one line...

```
const getUser = () => (Cookies.getJSON('user') || {}).user
```